# Is there an efficient way to compute the (top entries of) the parity spectrum of a function on the Boolean cube?

Tags: fourier-analysis

Suppose I have the Boolaen cube $B=\{-1, 1\}^n$, and let $F$ be the $2^n$ dimensional space of real-valued functions on it. Then the parity functions form a basis for $F$:

$$b_S(x)=\prod_{i\in S}x_i,\quad S\subseteq \{1,...,n\}$$

For an arbitrary function $f\in F$, I would like to compute the *top* (in absolute value) coordinates of $f$ with respect to the parity basis. I would like to do this for values of $n$ in the hundreds or thousands, which rules out something like the [Hadamard transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Walsh%E2%80%93Hadamard_transform) which is still super-exponential in $n$. Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

I would basically like to do something like "compression", like grabbing just the top few terms in a signal's Fourier series. Maybe getting the top coordinates by absolute value isn't even the "right" way to do this?

Comment: The first thing I'd try is to find the complexity of the subproblem where $f$ is one of the $b_S$, so that computing the top coordinates amounts to finding $S$.

Comment: what is your exact definition of "top"? The top $k$ coefficients in terms of absolute value? The smallest number $k$ of coefficients whose sum of squares is above some threshold? what is the goal of this "compression"?

Comment: You seem to be asking for the Kushilevitz-Mansour algorithm (see, e.g., Theorem 38 in [these lecture notes](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~rocco/Teaching/S14/Scribe/lectures_full.pdf).

Comment: @ClementC. Yes, I've been reading the book by Ryan O'Donnell in the meantime and came across that, I haven't gotten into it yet but it struck me as relevant immediately